# I'm trying to add objects to NSMutableArray, but it won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am new to Objective-C and still have some difficulties understanding some things. Below I try to declare an **NSMutableArray** in *@interface* and then in *@implementation* I'm getting an JSON from my localhost and trying to add the data into my **NSMutableArray**. However, it won't work for some reasons.

I am reading everything I can find online, but anyway I don't understand what I did wrong. Here is the code inside my *TableViewController.m* :

```
    @interface ScoresListTableViewController ()
    {
        NSMutableArray* dataSource;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ScoresListTableViewController


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8082/cp_panel/pages/includes/functions.php"]];

        NSURLSessionTask *task = [[self getURLSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^( NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSError *jsonError;
                NSArray *parsedJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

                // Here I'm trying to add the objects from received JSON

                dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [dataSource addObject:parsedJsonArray];

                NSLog(@"%@", dataSource); // Outputs the data fine


            });
        }];

        [task resume];

        // But here it will output empty array ()
        NSLog(@"%@", dataSource);

}

- (NSURLSession *)getURLSession {
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once( &onceToken,
                  ^{
                      NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                      session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
                  });
    return session;
}
```

I will appreciate if you will take your time and explain me what I did wrong.

Best Regards !

Comment: When you call `[task resume]` it returns immediately -- it does not wait for completion of the task. So `dataSource` is not set yet. Try putting the code that depends on `dataSource` in the completion handler.

Comment: What you are missing is "asynchronous". The `NSLog(@"%@", dataSource);` are not print the same order as you think.

Comment: Thank you guys, i tried a different way and now it kind of works better. But thank you for letting me know ! Appreciate it